# How to harmonise sharps or flats key

Tags: harmony

As I know the pattern to harmonise the key are 1 3 &5 , but how do you harmonise the sharps or flats ? As I tried the 1 3&5 pattern in keyboard and it doesn't sounds good. Thanks

Comment: Could we get you to further elaborate on your question? It is a bit unclear as is.

Answer (score 2):

Harmonising using 1,3,5 is using the first, third and fifth of a scale to make a triad. Generally, that scale will be a major or minor. So, for example, you could use C,E,G from the C major scale, or E,G,B from the E minor scale. The sharps and flats work in exactly the same way. Take F,A,C, making an F major, and sharpen each, F#,A#,C#, to make F# major. Flats the same. Lets take A major - A,C#,E. To make Ab major, it's Ab,C natural,Eb. We've flattened the A and E, and effectively flattened the C# by taking it down a semitone to C. Any key with # or b in it will use those specific notes as 1,3,5 to make a triad.

In any particular key, you can also use 2,4,6 or 3,5,7 or 4,6,8 or 5,7,9 or 6,8,10 or 7,9,11. All these will make the 3 major, 3 minor and 1 diminished triads for that key.